# Finding Duplicate values for nvarchar type in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below and need to find only duplicate values from it

```
Name    ID       ID1         ID3
----------------------------------
AB1   234ACB     BCD123   EFD234
AB2   54IFT     
AB3   56TYI     
AB4   234ACB     BCD123 
AB5         
AB6   IT456               EFD234
AB7              BCD123   EFD234
```

The result I expected from it

```
Name    ID       ID1         ID3
----------------------------------
AB1   234ACB    BCD123      EFD234
AB4   234ACB    BCD123  
AB6   IT456                 EFD234
AB7             BCD123      EFD234
```

The below query did not display any output

```
SELECT 
    Name, ID, ID1, ID3 
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Name, ID, ID1, ID3
HAVING
    COUNT(ID) > 1 
    AND COUNT(ID1) > 1 
    AND COUNT(ID3) > 1
```

Comment: When you group by name the uniqueness is there, just look at your code and you will see.  This means you end up not having anything with a count > 1 because you have included your a GROUP BY your name column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick the correct ID,ID1 and ID3 and use them to get the rows

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   Name VARCHAR(3),
>   ID VARCHAR(6),
>   ID1 VARCHAR(6),
>   ID3 VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (Name, ID, ID1, ID3)
> VALUES
>   ('AB1', '234ACB', 'BCD123', 'EFD234'),
>   ('AB2', '54IFT', NULL, NULL),
>   ('AB3', '56TYI', NULL, NULL),
>   ('AB4', '234ACB', 'BCD123', NULL),
>   ('AB5', NULL, NULL, NULL),
>   ('AB6', 'IT456', NULL, 'EFD234'),
>   ('AB7', 'BCD123', NULL, 'EFD234');
> GO
> ```

7 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table1  GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1)
> OR
> ID1 IN (SELECT ID1 FROM table1  GROUP BY ID1 HAVING COUNT(ID1) > 1)
> OR
> ID3 IN (SELECT ID3 FROM table1  GROUP BY ID3 HAVING COUNT(ID3) > 1)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | ID     | ID1    | ID3   
> :--- | :----- | :----- | :-----
> AB1  | 234ACB | BCD123 | EFD234
> AB4  | 234ACB | BCD123 | null  
> AB6  | IT456  | null   | EFD234
> AB7  | BCD123 | null   | EFD234
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f2751b8ea82aacf51a6d1f6fae63fef7)*

Comment: Is there a way to order them similar IDs?

Comment: you can order by column ascending or descing  LIKE ODER BY ID,ID1,ID3  the order here will determine the order of the rows, but you didn't specify the order in your question

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking you can use window functions:

```
select name, id1, id2, id3
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id1) as cnt1,
             count(*) over (partition by id2) as cnt2,
             count(*) over (partition by id3) as cnt3
     from t
    ) t
where (id1 is not null and cnt1 > 1) or
      (id2 is not null and cnt2 > 1) or
      (id3 is not null and cnt3 > 1);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon but I am expecting different name on it

Comment: `partition by  idX`  I guess

Comment: @JoeSwift . . .Just remove `name` from the `partition by`.

Answer (score 0):

Exists version

```
select name, id, id1, id3
from  table1 t
where exists (select 1 
             from table1 t2
             where t.name <> t2.name 
               and (t.id = t2.id or t.id1 = t2.id1 or t.id3 = t2.id3))
order by name;
```